# Failed to fetch locations information for mobile services - Error 400

Tags: azure

I try to follow Scotts introduction for Azure on this page:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started/

But already at point 4 when I intend to create a new mobile service there is an error.
I briefly see the white dialog coming up and the combobox for Region says "Loading ..."
Then the dialog quickly disappers and I get the following error message.

> Failed to fetch locations information for mobile services - Error 400
>   Browser: 5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4 User Language:  Email: (my
>   email)

User Language not stated made my a little suspicous.
I checked in Chrome but language is specified, so nothing wrong there.
I then tried IE 10 and got similar result.
User Language is now actually detected correct which is nice, but error message is still the same.

> Failed to fetch locations information for mobile services - Error 400
>   Browser: 5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Zune 4.7)
>   User Language: sv-SE
>   Email: (my email)

I guess this is a problem with the preview version of Azure site.
Is there anything I can do to get it working?

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with the service. See this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835597/unable-to-create-azure-mobile-service

Comment: OK, thanks for the reference. I guess I just wait and hope they fix it  soon ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few users seem to be running into this issue and as far as we can tell its related to having multiple subscriptions on your Azure account, some of which are not enabled for Mobile Services. Can you try the following:

1. Go to https://manage.windowsazure.com
2. Login with the account you use for Mobile Services (or any other Azure service)
3. Click on the top bar so you can see options
4. Click "ACCOUNT" (you may need to provide password again)
5. Click "preview features" at the top
6. Add the Mobile Services feature for each of your subscriptions (sign up again if it already says you are signed up)
7. Wait a couple of minutes so that the addition goes through the usual automated process

If this does not work, can you please mail me at pbatum@microsoft.com so I can follow up?