# Unable to create Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to fetch locations information for mobile services - Error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835348/failed-to-fetch-locations-information-for-mobile-services-error-400)

Lately I have got a Azure trial subscription to try out Mobile services, but whenever I try to create the

new Mobile service I get this error message. Is there any solution to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with the service. See this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835348/failed-to-fetch-locations-information-for-mobile-services-error-400