# Unable to create Azure Mobile Service: Error 500

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I can't create a mobile Service in Azure: I receive that there's an error at calling the location information for mobile services: Error 500:

Fehler beim Abrufen der Standortinformationen für mobile Services: Fehler 500.
Wiederholen Sie den Vorgang. Sollte das Problem weiterhin bestehen, wenden Sie sich an den Support.

Note that its not an error 400 as in the similar question [Unable to create Azure Mobile Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835597/unable-to-create-azure-mobile-service).

Comment: There was an issue in the service from 9:00UTC to roughly 12:00UTC which could have caused your problem. Can you try it again to see if it has been fixed? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, same thing. Just one thing: After registering for the 3 month test account, I got the welcome e-mails. 20 Minutes later I got some aknowledge message that the 3 month test account was successfully resigned, which I have never done... So I'm not sure if it's a normal thing that the test account resigns it self with 3 month period???

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I can provide additional information:

I got this error message as well, along with the "Error 500" mentioned above:

```
{"message":"Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.","ErrorMessage":"Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.","httpStatusCode":"InternalServerError","operationTrackingId":"","stackTrace":null,"Padding":null}
```

For this, the only thing that worked for me was creating a brand new SQL database with 20MB on a new server and using the username & password I chose when I created that server.

Answer (score 3):

I had to go into my existing azure sql database server and under the configuration tab select "yes" to allow azure services to access the server.

Note: this is the configuration for the server not the database.

Once I did this, I tried again to create my mobile service and it worked.

Comment: Working! But now the option "Allow access to Azure services" is under the "Show firewall settings" link.
Don't forget to click "save" !